# PyCharm: при debug не отображается картинка (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

Изучаю OpenCV, отображаю фрагмент картинки из файла:

```
img_NZ_bgr = cv2.imread("New_Zealand_Boat.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_NZ_rgb = img_NZ_bgr[:,:,::-1]
cropped_region = img_NZ_rgb[200:400, 300:600]
plt.imshow(cropped_region)
plt.title("Sailboat");
plt.show()
```

все ОК
далее, изменяю размеры этой картинки и вновь ее отображаю,
[image: вот так:]
если запустить этот код в режиме "Run" (PyCharm), то картинка отображается, все ок
но если запустить этот же код в режиме "Debug" - картинка не отображается.

Comment: ну, то есть. претензии не к python или opencv, а к pycharm? потому что в заголовке вопрос и в тегах вы упомянули все, кроме ide

Comment: помилуйте, какие могут быть претензии к opencv или к python? Код очевидно работает (при использовании Run). Но может быть, кто - нибудь знает, что изменяется, если PyCharm использует Debug?